# Get number (date) and plus 1 (day)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to modify someone else's code hence the roundabout way of doing this, unfortunately I have no option.

I have a jQuery variable which is `var calc_date_to = jQuery('#date_to').val();` which gets the value of an input box. The value of this input box is a number in the form '04.02.2014' which represents a date.

I have another input box which takes this date and adds it to it's value, this bit of jQuery is `$('#date_to_new').val(calc_date_to);`, this all works perfectly.

The problem is, The number that I want to show in my second input box needs to be a day in advance. Therefore if the value of 'calc_date_to' is '04.02.2014' then I want the value of the second input box to be '05.02.2014'.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are all dates localized? Are you worrying about localization?

Comment: Are you using the jQuery datepicker?

Comment: Also, if you need to do this more than a handful of times I would recommend bringing in a date handling library like the fantastic [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Date` object, add one day and then render the string egain:

```
// Parse date
var raw = "31.12.2014".split(".");
var myDate = new Date(raw[2], raw[1]-1, raw[0]);
// Add one day
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+1);
// Render date
var final = [myDate.getDate(), myDate.getMonth()+1, myDate.getFullYear()].join(".");
```

**Note:** the `-1` and `+1` is used, because the date library uses `0` as the first month, not `1`.

Check this example here: http://jsfiddle.net/hyYNp/

Comment: Thanks for this but I get something strange going on. If the original date is '21.03.2014' then the new date is '3.9.26' etc...

Comment: @DesignSubway I have fixed it. Now it's 100% correct, and it doesn't uses libraries... Try to include libraries ONLY when needed! They slow down a LOT your page load, and makes your code slower...

Comment: @IvanSeidel I completely disagree. To say that libraries slow down your page load a "LOT" is ridiculous. OP is already using jQuery which is ~40kb. Assuming his page has css and images as any web page would, then you're looking at several hundred kb of data to download. Moment.js is 9.3kb. This will not slow down the page load time in any way as to be noticeable by a user. Aside from that, it means he has a well tested, flexible & powerful date library which abstracts the complexities of date arithmetic away, thereby massively reducing the possibility of making a mistake (which is high)

Comment: I work with massive data. 1kb is enough to generate GB's of data. If you think this way, then 40kb isn't enough, plus 50kb not even. 15kb, why to consider... And in the end, you will have the avarage 1MB site, witch is `natural` nowdays, but shouldn't. Considering images, html, libraries... And also, slowdown is not on the pageload only. We need to parse, and compile that 40kb of js, and it also takes time. For my i7, it even senses such things, but for an mobile phone, things change. Only use libraries when you REALLY need, and you will be happy. Libraries spare you dev TIME in most of cases.

Comment: Also, the code I wrote has 248Bytes. That's about 40x less than Moment.js, and they actually do the same, if he is just going to 'add' one day. JavaScript has a decent library of Time, and people should use it for compatibility.

Comment: @IvanSeidel Re: bandwidth use, that's nothing to do with page load time. Re: bandwidth, I agree if you have a massive site. Re: mobile phone, I think the performance hit is debatable. Re: using libraries only when you really need to, in a single instance I agree with you. But in my experience requirements change, features get added, code grows more complex. Chances are there will be some other date arithmetic required, and in my experience date arithmetic is a nightmare (leap years, time zones, etc) and should be left to a library. I'd always take a 9.3kb hit over getting it wrong.

Comment: @theyetiman Re Bandwidth: The size of the file dosn't change a lot on loading, the 'requesting' thing does.. about 250ms, even for a 100byte file or 1kb. Re: I love libraries, I just don't like to be 'dependent'on them 100%... In fact, if my website was something that REALLY needed to work with time, I would be using it. Re: leap years are handled by Javascript core library Class 'Date': http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: @IvanSeidel I'm not saying Javascript can't do this stuff natively, just that a library allows for more readable, maintainable and therefore better code where mistakes are less likely to occur. It's just my opinion so let's just agree to disagree. Either way I'm glad OP got his problem solved! :)

Comment: @theyetiman That's ok. I like robust code (and redundant) when needed =)

Answer (score 1):

### Use a date library

I would seriously consider using a Javascript date library. moment.js is my favourite.

Get it here: http://momentjs.com/

Minimal coding, maximum flexibility without having to fret over the complexities of the calendar system we use.

Then you can just do:

```
var format = 'DD.MM.YYYY'; //assuming this is always the format
var calc_date_to = jQuery('#date_to').val();
var firstDate = moment(calc_date_to, format);
var secondDate = firstDate.add('d',1);
$('#date_to_new').val(secondDate.format(format));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
function calcDate(str) {
    var d = str.split('.');
    return new Date ( new Date(d[2],d[1]-1,d[0]).getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 );
}

calcDate('04.02.2014');

// OUTPUTS
// Date {Wed Feb 05 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time)}
```

This creates date object from that string, extracts the timestamp, adds in the number of ticks in a day, and returns new date object with +1 day.

Comment: A thing to note here (and that the OP has not clarified) is that many cultures write their dates differently, possibly even in a different order. You would ideally let the browser culture parse the string then use the invariant `.getYear()`, `.getMonth()`, `.getDate()` api.